# I added 4 elements in the linked list, but why only three are displayed and the last element is not printed

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is my code. Please help me in finding out why the last element of the linkedlist is not getting printed and how can I print the last element too.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

def append(self, data):
    current = self.head
    if self.head:
        while current.next:
            current= current.next
        current.next= data
    else:
        self.head = data

def show(self):
    current = self.head
    while current.next:
        print(current.value)
        current = current.next


ll1=LinkedList()
e1= Node(1)
e2 = Node(2)
e3 = Node(3)
e4 = Node(4)

ll1.append(e1)
ll1.append(e2)
ll1.append(e3)
ll1.append(e4)
ll1.show()
```

[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HAsy.png)

Comment: `current.next` of the last node will always be `None`, this will terminate the while loop before printing the last node.

Comment: use `while current` for termination condition in `show` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because e3.next is e4, but e4.next is None. So the while loop will end at e3.

Just change the show function like this:

```
def show(self):
    current = self.head
    while current.next:
        print(current.value)
        current = current.next
        if not current.next:
            print(current.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

last element hasn't next element so not printed; you can change code to do-while format like bottom

```
def show(self):
    current = self.head
    while True:
        print(current.value)
        current = current.next
        if not current:
            break
```